# How to find and replace multiple words from paragraph with identified next word in python?

Tags: python, string, replace

I want to replace and tag multiple words from a paragraph with their next word.

```
paragraph = "Python is the most powerful language [YES] yes. my sex is [NO] male [YES] female"
```

I want to replace the keys [YES] and [NO] with their next word like below.

```
paragraph = "Python is the most powerful language [YES]yes[/YES]. my sex is [NO]male[/NO] [YES]female[/YES]"
```

Comment: would you tell us why you're doing this. there could be a simpler way

Comment: actually i am processing a scanned pdf that contains check boxes. after object detection and ocr i will get a paragraph like this, check boxes will be  replaced by this  [YES] and [NO] keys. i just want to replace this keys with their next words.

Comment: You can use regex. search for "[YES]" followed by space and then by a set of characters and ends with space. S+ would match anything that is not a space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Regular expressions** to achieve the result:
Here is the code:

```
import re

paragraph = "Python is the most powerful language [YES] yes. my sex is [NO] male [YES] female"

paragraph = re.sub(r"\[(.*?)\]\s\b(\w+)\b", r"[\1]\2[/\1]", paragraph)
```

Output is:

```
"Python is the most powerful language [YES]yes[/YES]. my sex is [NO]male[/NO] [YES]female[/YES]"
```

Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 0):

```
paragraph = "Python is the most powerful language [YES] yes. my sex is [NO] male [YES] female"

def find_replace(paragraph):
    par = paragraph.split(" ")
    for i, p in enumerate(par):
        if p == "[NO]":
            par[i] = "[NO]" + par[i+1] + "[/NO]"
            del par[i+1]

    # the same for [YES]

    return " ".join(par)
```